# Calculate difference in rows recorded at different timestamp in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table with data as follows

```
  Person_ID Date    Sale
    1        2016-05-08     2686
    1       2016-05-09      2688
    1       2016-05-14      2689
    1       2016-05-18      2691
    1       2016-05-24      2693
    1       2016-05-25      2694
    1       2016-05-27      2695
```

and there are a million such id's for different people. Sale count is recorded only when a sale increases else it is not. Therefore data for id' 2 can be different from id 1.

```
  Person_ID Date    Sale
    2       2016-05-10      26
    2       2016-05-20      29
    2       2016-05-18      30
    2       2016-05-22      39
    2       2016-05-25      40
```

Sale count of 29 on 5/20 means he sold 3 products on 20th, and had sold 26 till 5/10 with no sale in between these 2 dates.

Question: I want a sql/dynamic sql to calculate the daily a sales of all the agents and produce a report as follows:

```
  ID  Sale_511  Sale_512   Sale_513 --------------   Sale_519   Sale_520

   2     0          0          0     ---------------    0          3
                                                                (29-26)
```

Question is how do I use that data to calculate a report. As I do have data between 5/20 to 5/10. SO i can just write a query saying A-B = C?

Can anyone help? Thank you.

P.S - New to SQL so learning.

Using Sql Server 2008.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: "I want a SQL" is not a question. Please ask a question.

Comment: Question is how do I use that data to calculate a report. As I do have data between 5/20 to 5/10. SO i can just write a query saying A-B = C?

Comment: @nk771 Edit your Question to clarify rather than post as comments.

Comment: I think these are **dates** not **timestamps** -- you might notice there is no time information included.  This is what makes them a date.

Answer (score 0):

Most SQL dialects support the `lag()` function.  You can get what you want as:

```
select person_id, date,
       (sale - lag(sale) over (partition by person_id, date)) as Daily_Sales
from t;
```

This produces one row per date for each person.  This format is more typical for how SQL would return such results.

In SQL Server 2008, you can do:

```
select t.person_id, t.date,
       (t.sale - t2.sale) as Daily_Sales
from t outer apply
     (select top 1 t2.*
      from t t2
      where t2.person_id = t.person_id and t2.date < t.date
     ) t2
```

Comment: I am on SQL Server 2008. Lag function is invalid.